# What does this mean in this context? このキャンプ場と言う名の森なら熊が出てもおかしくは無い。(A character is making BBQ on a camping site, inside a forest)

Tags: meaning, manga, japanese-to-english

I do not quite understand his thought here, especially the 1st part.

> このキャンプ場と言う名の森なら熊が出てもおかしくは無い。

(My guess but not sure: "If this camping site is also called a forest, then I wouldn't be surprised when it also has bears")

Answer (score 4):

You can read キャンプ場と言う名の森 literally as *this forest called a ‘campsite’*, or less literally as: “this so-called campsite that I would really call a forest.”

I'm guessing that in the context of your manga, someone else is talking about a campsite, and the speaker of this line thinks the campsite is *so* dangerous-looking and forest-like that (a) it doesn't deserve to be called a campsite, and (b) it wouldn't be out-of-place for a bear to show up.